# What are good values for autocorrelation, Gelman, and cross-correlation in rjags?

Tags: bayesian, autocorrelation, markov-chain-montecarlo, jags, cross-correlation

I don't want to post my whole code since it is long, so I will only post part of it:

```
model <- jags.model('model.txt', data=previous, inits=inits, n.chains=3)

update(model, 20000)
mcmc_samples <- coda.samples(model, variable.names=c('b.0','b.X', 'b.Ratio', 'b.pct', 'b.per',),n.iter=200000,thin=100)
post_samples <- jags.samples(model, variable.names=c('b.0','b.X', 'b.Ratio', 'b.pct', 'b.per',),n.iter=200000,thin=100)
```

I then checked the Gelman diagnostic, cross correlation, and autocorrelation.

```
gelman.diag(mcmc_samples)
crosscorr(mcmc_samples)
autocorr.plot(mcmc_samples)
```

For the gelman, the highest `Upper C.I.`  for a variable I got was 1.08. I also got a few values in the .42-.46 range for the `crosscorr`. Are these acceptable?

However, for the autocorrelation, the plots for some variables clearly did not converge to 0. How can I improve this? Do I have to exclude some variables from the regression and MCMC?

Or do I have to increase the number of iterations or burn-ins? If so, how do I do that?

Comment: Andrew Gelman is definitely one of the better values of Gelman.

Comment: @Sycorax ...it takes also other values, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelman

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to suggest excluding variables without seeing your model. With the code you post above, you can increase the burn-in steps by increasing the number in the call to jags.update().  The number of iterations is indicated with the value you set as n.iter.  It doesn't appear the call to jags.samples() is doing anything for you here.

There are a lot of opinions out there about convergence, but in general I look for a Gelman-Rubin statistic less than 1.05.